# Function not renaming field pulled from another page

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form which is cloned when needed, inside this form I have a div, this div is replaced by a div pulled from another page which has new select options based on a select option from a above field.

Each 'cloned' forms fields are given a new name with a function, but this function seems to have trouble seeing the field that is pulled in as part of the form and isn't generating a new name for it.

Could Someone kind enough show me the way please?

function;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newNum = 2;
    cloneMe = function(el) {
        var newElem = el.clone().attr('id', 'container' + newNum);
        newElem.html(newElem.html().replace(/form\[1\]/g, 'form['+newNum+']'));
        newElem.html(newElem.html().replace(/id="(.*?)"/g, 'id="1'+newNum+'"'));
        $('#cloneb').before(newElem);
        $('#delete_name'+ newNum).html('<p id="rem_field"><a href="#"><span>Delete Line</span></a></p>');
        newNum++;
    };

    $('p#rem_field').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('div').remove();
    return false;
});    

});
```

form;

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' name='form' id='form'>
    <div id="container1">
        <div class="instance" id="instance">
            <label>Style:</label>
                <select name='form[1][style]' id='style' class='style' onchange="showDim(this)">
                    <option value='0' class='red'>Select a style...</option>            
                        <?php
                        include ('connect.php');
                            $getsty = $db->prepare("SELECT Style_ID, Style_Type FROM style ORDER BY Style_Type ASC LIMIT 1, 18446744073709551615;"); 
                            $getsty->execute();
                                while($row = $getsty->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {    
                                    $Style_ID = $row['Style_ID'];
                                    $Style_Type = $row['Style_Type'];                   
                                    echo "      <option value='$Style_ID'>$Style_Type</option>";
                                }                                       
                        ?>   
                </select>                           
            <br />
            <div class='dimdiv'>                    
                <label>Dimensions:</label>
                    <select name='form[1][Dim]' id='Dim'>
                        <option value='0' class='red'>Select the dimensions...</option> 
                    </select>
            </div>
            <br />
            <label>Colour:</label>
                <select name='form[1][Colour]' id='Colour'>
                    <option value='0' class='red'>Select a colour...</option>
                    <option value='Colour1'>Colour #1</option>
                    <option value='Colour2'>Colour #2</option>
                    <option value='Colour3'>Colour #3</option>
                    <option value='Colour4'>Colour #4</option>
                </select>
            <br />  
            <label>Quantity:</label> 
                <input type='text' name='form[1][Quantity]' id='Quantity'>
            <br />              
        </div>  
        <div id="delete_name" style="margin:15px 0px 0px 0px; width:120px; height:30px;"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="cloneb" value="Clone" onclick="cloneMe($('#container1'));" />
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' class='buttons'>
</form>
```

Field pulled from get_dim.php;

```
<label>Dimensions:</label>
    <select name='form[1][Dim]' id='Dim'>
        <option value='0' class="red">Select the dimensions...</option>                 
            <?php       

            $id = intval($_GET['id']);

            include ('connect.php');
            $getcus = $db->prepare("SELECT Dim_ID, Dim FROM dimentions WHERE Style_ID=? ORDER BY Dim ASC "); 
            $getcus->execute(array($id));
            while($row = $getcus->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {    
                $Dim_ID = $row['Dim_ID'];
                $Dim = $row['Dim'];                 
                echo "      <option value='$Dim_ID'>$Dim</option>";
                }   
            ?>
    </select>
```

Function to replace the dimdiv with get_dim.php;

```
function showDim(elem)
{
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('style'),
        groupIndex = -1,
        targetDimDiv,
        i;
    for( i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i ) {
        if( elems[i] == elem ) {
            groupIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( groupIndex == -1 )
    {
        return;
    }
    targetDimDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('dimdiv')[groupIndex];
    if (elem.value == "")
    {
        targetDimDiv.innerHTML="";
        return;
    }       
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function( ) {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
            targetDimDiv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };          
    xmlhttp.open("GET","get_dim.php?id="+elem.value,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Hi, where is the problem? in get_dim.php?

Comment: no the get_dim.php function works fine, it the naming of the field contained in get_dim.php done by the cloneing function that doesnt work, when i dump $_Post the Dim field is only part of the 1st form and not part of the clones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, that `form[1][Dim]` is hard coded into `get_dim.php`. When you clone a form, you change the name of every element, but this AJAX request would still return a form element with name `form[1][Dim]` there too.

You can fix this, by reading out the current form id and passing it to `get_dim.php` and making the name generation there dynamic.

The parts you have to change (roughly):

replace function:

```
form_id = groupIndex + 1; // if I get groupIndex right
xmlhttp.open("GET","get_dim.php?id="+elem.value+"&form_id="+form_id,true);
```

get_dim.php:

```
<select name='form[<?php echo intval($_GET['form_id']); ?>][Dim]' id='Dim'>
```

Comment: Hmm I understand what your saying but I'm having trouble with the `form_id` part, It needs to be pulled from the cloning function I think as the way you've suggested give me `'form_<?= intval($_GET[' => string '4' (length=1)` in the var dump of POST removing any reference to the dim div